# How to use Left-Shift to run?

Tags: unity, c#, movement, input

I need to use Left-Shift to run, but I can't figure out how to do so.

Here my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// This script moves the character controller forward
// and sideways based on the arrow keys.
// It also jumps when pressing space.
// Make sure to attach a character controller to the same game object.
// It is recommended that you make only one call to Move or SimpleMove per frame.

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    CharacterController characterController;

    public float speed = 6.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;
    public Transform charBody;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    public float mouseSense = 11f;
    public float runSpeed = 12f;
    public bool isRunning = false;

    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            // We are grounded, so recalculate
            // move direction directly from axes

            moveDirection = transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            moveDirection *= speed;
            moveDirection = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            moveDirection *= speed;





            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            {
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
            }
        }
           
        

        // Apply gravity. Gravity is multiplied by deltaTime twice (once here, and once below
        // when the moveDirection is multiplied by deltaTime). This is because gravity should be applied
        // as an acceleration (ms^-2)
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        // Move the controller
        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

        float MOUSEY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSense * Time.deltaTime;
        float MOUSEX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSense * Time.deltaTime;

        charBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * MOUSEX);

        


    }
}
```

When Left-Shift is pressed I want the speed to change to runSpeed.

Comment: Related is Unity's new input system:  https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html

Answer (score 2):

First I would rename the variable `speed` to `walkSpeed` to better differentiate it from `runSpeed`. Then I would create a local variable `speed` in `Update` and assign it based on the current state of the shift key:

```
float speed;
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
    speed = runSpeed;
} else {
    speed = walkSpeed;
}
```

This architecture also allows to take other circumstantial modifiers to the character speed into account.

Then I would use that local speed variable to calculate the moveDirection:

```
Vector3 input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
moveDirection = transform.right * input * runSpeed;

moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

````
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// This script moves the character controller forward
// and sideways based on the arrow keys.
// It also jumps when pressing space.
// Make sure to attach a character controller to the same game object.
// It is recommended that you make only one call to Move or SimpleMove per frame.

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    CharacterController characterController;

    public float speed = 6.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;
    public Transform charBody;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    public float mouseSense = 11f;
    public float runSpeed = 12f;
    public bool isRunning = false;
    float camRot = 0f;
    public Transform altCamera;

    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            // We are grounded, so recalculate
            // move direction directly from axes

            moveDirection = transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            moveDirection *= speed;
            moveDirection = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            moveDirection *= speed;





            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            {
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                moveDirection = transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
                moveDirection *= runSpeed;
                moveDirection = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
                moveDirection *= runSpeed;

            }
        }
           
        

        // Apply gravity. Gravity is multiplied by deltaTime twice (once here, and once below
        // when the moveDirection is multiplied by deltaTime). This is because gravity should be applied
        // as an acceleration (ms^-2)
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        // Move the controller
        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

        float MOUSEY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSense * Time.deltaTime;
        float MOUSEX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSense * Time.deltaTime;



        charBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * MOUSEX);

        



        


    }
}
```
````

Comment: Your solution makes the character move twice per update. One time with the regular speed and then again with the enhanced run speed. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Are you sure? It's not doing so for me....

Comment: Ah OK, I misread that the `moveDirection` gets *set* twice but only gets *applied* to the characterController once. Still pretty wasteful to first calculate the  `moveDirection` according to the regular speed, and then when shift is pressed discard that calculation and repeat it with `runSpeed` instead of `Speed`.

Comment: Wait, you are calculating and discarding the `moveDirection`  *twice*. You are first calculating it with `transform.forward` and then you overwrite that result with another value calculated with `transform.right`. In both the regular speed and the runSpeed calculation. Why?